# Count and group row in MySql

Tags: mysql

I use Mysql database version 5.5.24-log.

In this table, I can not count and group the values ​​of field Premium_name.

In output I need 2 as the final value because in the table there are only two Premium_name: HYDROSPEED and GLOCKENSPIELMEMORIAL.

Thank you in advance.

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*), Premium_name
FROM
    `table_premium`
GROUP BY
    Premium_name;

+----------+----------------------+
| COUNT(*) | Premium_name         |
+----------+----------------------+
|        2 | GLOCKENSPIELMEMORIAL |
|        6 | HYDROSPEED           |
+----------+----------------------+
2 rows in set


+--------------+------------------+----------------------+--------------+
| Premium_area | Premium_sub_area | Premium_name         | Premium_code |
+--------------+------------------+----------------------+--------------+
| 51PD         | 51PDK1           | HYDROSPEED           |     48069794 |
| 51PD         | 51PDK1           | HYDROSPEED           |     48069795 |
| 51PD         | 51PDK1           | HYDROSPEED           |     49301672 |
| 51PD         | 51PDK1           | HYDROSPEED           |     52480075 |
| 51PD         | 51PDK1           | HYDROSPEED           |     52646404 |
| 51PD         | 51PDK1           | HYDROSPEED           |     91189540 |
| 51PD         | 51PDK2           | GLOCKENSPIELMEMORIAL |     45824206 |
| 51PD         | 51PDK2           | GLOCKENSPIELMEMORIAL |     48479834 |
+--------------+------------------+----------------------+--------------+
```

Comment: Do you want the `Premium_Name` returned with the result? Please post a sample table of exactly what output you expect your query to produce (though it might be as simple as `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Premium_Name) FROM table_premium`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Premium_name), Premium_name 
FROM
    `table_premium`
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) AS PREMIUMS FROM
(SELECT
 DISTINCT Premium_name
 FROM
`table_premium`)CS
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Premium_name), Premium_name FROM table_premium group by Premium_name